# Possible causes of rotational axle play and rattling

Tags: repair, drivetrain, saturn, axle, aura

Car is a 2007 Saturn Aura AT

A while ago I ran into a large rock with my passenger front wheel, insurance paid for the apparent damage but about a week later I started feeling rattling from that wheel, which has only gotten worse since. I examined the wheel bearing, which was notchy, so I replaced that yesterday.

While replacing, I felt for play in the CV axle, and found I could rotate it about 1/8 of a turn before hearing movement in the differential. Additionally, I can hear very light squeaking coming from the area of the inner CV joint while in the car. What are possible causes? Is this as simple as replacing the CV axle or are there other things I should look at first?

Comment: When you say "apparent damage", are you talking about the body work? If it was more than body damage fixed by insurance and you find subsequent damage, you should be able to get this taken care of as part of that insurance claim. I would bet you wouldn't even need to pay a further deductible.

Comment: It is quite possible that the CV joint  bearings were damaged and it wasn't evident until the vehicle was driven for awhile.  It won't hurt to ask the insurance company for an adjustment. I wouldn't be surprised if they claim that a 10 year old axle was due for replacement prior to the accident. The worst they can do is say no.

Comment: I should have added, I contacted the insurance company as soon as the rattling started and they said there was nothing they could do, but the damage that they repaired was bodywork, replacing tie rod, and replacing steering rack

Comment: @mikes I don't want to take it apart just to inspect and have to take it apart again to repair it, is it likely if I just replace the entire CV axle assembly that it'll fix whatever issue it might be?